# Partial derivatives of a composed function $F = g \circ \mathbf{f}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find the formulas for the partial derivatives of a compound function $F := g \circ \mathbf{f}$, with (my answer is in red):

1. $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z)$ and $g(u,v)$:

$$ \color{red}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(\mathbf{f}(x,y,z))\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,y,z) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(\mathbf{f}(x,y,z))\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x,y,z).}$$ Similarly, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$.

2. $\mathbf{f}(x,y)$ and $g(u,v)$:
   $$ \color{red}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(\mathbf{f}(x,y))\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(\mathbf{f}(x,y))\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x,y).}$$

Similarly, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$.

3. $\mathbf{f}(x)$ and $g(u,v)$:

$$ \color{red}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(\mathbf{f}(x))\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(\mathbf{f}(x))\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x).}$$

4. $f(x,y)$ and $g(u)$:

$$ \color{red}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{d g}{du}(f(x,y))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y).}$$

Similarly, $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$.

Is this correct? Especially the last one is making me doubt a bit.

Comment: $\mathbf f$ is a vector-valued function, with two components?

Comment: $\mathbf{f}$ is indeed a vector-valued function, but the number of components is not given. I assumed it has two, since in 1. - 3. $g$ is a function that takes two variables.

Comment: Well, it's fine for me, except in the  2rd case, you should write normal derivatives for $f_1$ and $f_2$.